# How to make box shadow work on all sides of a box

Tags: html, css

I am using a box shadow to create a vertical glowing line in a program frontend that I am writing with electron. The line appears between two large backgrounds and serves as a divider. Currently, the shadow is only appearing on the left side. What am I doing wrong and how can I make it exist on both sides? It currently looks like [this.](https://gyazo.com/de05bac7839c3cc370c6dc3105160193)

Here is style code for the section on the left and right, as well as the divider.

```
        .left {
          background-color: #00000d;
          width: 150px; 
          height: 500px; 
          float: left; 
          text-align: center;
          border-top-left-radius: 20px;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
        }
        .divider {
          background-color:yellow; 
          width: 5px; 
          height: 500px;
          float: left;
          box-shadow: 0 0 10px gold
        }
        .right {
          background-color: #00000d;
          width: 850px;
          height: 500px;
          float: left;
          border-top-right-radius: 20px;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
        }
```

Thanks for any help that anybody is able to provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your element with `.right` overlaps the box shadow on the right side. Try adding this to `.divider` as a workaround:

```css
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```